# Understanding the technical bits of quantising elastic waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, phonons

I'm reading Kittel's Solid State book and I have a number of 'simple-ish' questions regarding phonons. He starts with the hamiltonian
$$H=\sum_{s=1}^N\left[\dfrac{1}{2M}p_s^2+\dfrac{1}{2}C(q_{s+1}-q_s)^2 \right]$$
and tries to de-couple this by introducing the coordinates:
$$Q_k=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{s}q_se^{-jksa}$$
$$\Pi_k=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{s}p_se^{jksa}$$
Because Kittel imposed periodic boundary conditions ($q_{s+N}=q_s$), then the wavevector must be of the form $k=2\pi n/Na$ where $n=0,1,2,...,N/2$.

My first problem is how Kittel claimed:
$$\sum_re^{-j(k-k')ra}=\sum_re^{-2\pi j(n-n')r/N}=N\delta(k,k')$$
Kittel says this is a 'standard result' but I can't see why this sum is true?

Next, Kittel later asserts:
$$i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}Q_k=[Q_k,H]$$ but I thought that 'correct' relation was:
$$i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\langle Q_k\rangle=\langle[Q_k,H]\rangle+i\hbar\langle\dfrac{\partial Q_k}{\partial t}\rangle$$ Why are we not using averages and ignoring the second term?

My final question is less technical but more of a why. Kittel finally arrives at the energy eigenvalues by claiming that since we can show $$\ddot{Q_k}+w_k^2Q_k=0$$then we have a harmonic oscillator. Something about this argument bugs me since I see $Q_k$ as nothing real: it's just some coordinate transformation of $q_k$, which is what we're interested in. How do I make this logical leap?

Comment: I think most of your questions about $Q_k$ can be answered by googling the "Heisenberg picture" of quantum mechanics. Kittel is NOT using the usual, Schrodinger-equation based quantum mechanics, where the wavefunction evolves in time. He's using the Heisenberg representation, where instead operators evolve in time.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your first point, that equation is the orthogonality relation for the complex exponentials as a basis for periodic functions on a discrete set.  (This is equivalent to the sine and cosine basis used in more Fourier series, because the sines and cosines are simple linear combinations of complex exponentials.) Proofs of orthogonality relations that involve discrete sums are difficult and usually taken for granted by physicists.  However, they are often analogous to orthogonality relations with integrals instead of sums.  For example, using the functions $e^{ikx}$ as a basis for arbitrary square integrable functions on the real line, the orthogonality relation is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\,e^{-i(k-k')x}=2\pi\delta(k,k')$$
which can be proved from the Fourier transform inversion formula.  In fact, taking the limit as $a\rightarrow0$ but $Na\rightarrow\infty$, your formula reduces to the integral result.

That you are unfamiliar with this relation, as well as your third query, suggest that you may not be familiar with Fourier series decompositions.  (Your inconsistent use of "$j"$ to represent the imaginary unit also suggests that you may be coming from an electrical engineering background.)  There are many resources on this subject, in print and online—[this short set of notes, for example](http://core.csu.edu.cn/NR/rdonlyres/Physics/8-07Fall-2005/14F3A9AF-61EB-4242-B454-0A488C57DA0D/0/completeness.pdf), may give you a useful introduction.

On your second question, the equation
$$\frac{d{\cal O}}{dt}=\frac{1}{i\hbar}[{\cal O},H]$$
is the Heisenberg equation of motion for the operator ${\cal O}$ (with no explicit time dependence).  This was the way that [time dependence was first expressed in quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture), as the field was developed by Heisenberg.  Now, it is more common to use [Schrödinger's formulation of the theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture), in which the states of the theory depend on time, while operators typically do not.  In the Schrödinger picture, the equation you have cited with the expectation values holds (a result known as [Ehrenfest's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem)), but in the Heisenberg picture, the equation holds without even taking expectations.

While the Schrödinger is usually more useful, the Heisenberg picture can be more convenient when the focus is on operators.  In this case, Kittel is using the Heisenberg version, because he is developing the operator algebra for the phonon modes.  The phonon oscillations behave like simple harmonic oscillators, which are most easily studied in quantum mechanics using creation and annihilation operators.  As to the neglect of the last term in the operator equation of motion, involving $\partial{\cal Q_{k}}/\partial t$, Kittel has simply dropped it already, since the $Q_{k}$ quadrature operator as you have written it down does not depend explicitly on the variable $t$.

As to your third question, the variable $Q_{k}$ certainly does represent something real. It represents the amplitude of photon oscillations that have wave vector $k$ with a given phase. The conjugate momentum variable $\Pi_{k}$ is proportional to the amplitude for oscillations that are $90^{\circ}$ out of phase.

Comment: So if $\cal O$ has no explicit time dependence then why do we ignore the $\partial\cal O/\partial t$ term but not the $d\cal O/ dt$?

Comment: @AyumuKasugano The *partial* derivative $\partial{\cal O}/\partial t$ *means* the derivative that arises from the *explicit* time dependence.  See here, for example:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-a-time-dependent-operator.878579/#post-5520157